# Move Label left when Button is hidden

Tags: ios, swift, size-classes

i have a problem with size classes.

I have button on the left side of my view controller. just after it i have a label on its right side.

- distance between left edge of vc and button is 100
- distance between right edge of button and label is 10

it looks like this:

---- |button| - |label|

how to move label to the left edge of vc (100) in the place of button when i make button.hidden = true ?

---- |label|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're targeting iOS9 up then this is a perfect case to use a UIStackView. When the button is hidden the label will just move over automatically.

Also, if the button is being hidden because of a change to size class, you could just add the labels leading constraint to what you want to only apply for the size class where the button is hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Give leading constraint (set its value to same as button's to leading constraint's value) from label to left edge with Low priority. Change label to button constraint's priority to low. When button will be hidden, set low priority to high and high priority to low and call `layoutIfNeeded` method